# Google Sheets - Apps Script - cell reference in Round() function is not changing after copying

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my apps script when I copy a row of functions using .getFormulasR1C1() and then pasting them using .setFormulasR1C1() the cell references update as expected except for any cell reference within Round(). Example:

Formula in original cell:
=Round(B2)*$C5

When copied to the cell below using apps script becomes:
=Round(B2)*$C6

What can I do to have the reference cell in the Round() function also update as well?

Expected Outcome:
=Round(B3)*$C6

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: As I pasted the formula I also was inserting a new row which would force the cell reference to incorrectly reference. By copying the formula that was just created into the newly created row, the reference is accurate.